# How to force google colab and gspread to write strings and dates to google sheets in the correct and respective format

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-colaboratory, gspread

I have a dataframe that has a series with dates that look like this:
2022-06-01
and also series that have ids that look like this:
7582857e38

when I write the df to a google sheet I have 2 options when writing data:
`value_input_option = 'RAW'` or `value_input_option='USER_ENTERED'`

If I use RAW (the default), the id is written properly but the date is written as forced string
'2022-06-01

if I use USER_ENTERED, then some of id's are converted to a number in scientific notation  but the date is written properly.

is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,

I ended up writing the data frame to google sheets in 2 stages

1st stage: write the entire df as raw

2nd stage: make a temp df that would hold the date series(column) and then write over that column with user_entered

```
#write entire df as RAW
cam_ws.update([cam_df.columns.values.tolist()] + cam_df.values.tolist(),value_input_option='RAW')

#re-rewrite date columns as user-entered so they are interpreted as dates
Reseller_Order_Date_df = cam_df[['Reseller Order Date']]
cam_ws.update('J1',[Reseller_Order_Date_df.columns.values.tolist()] + Reseller_Order_Date_df.values.tolist(),value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
Expired_At_df = cam_df[['Expired At']]
cam_ws.update('P1',[Expired_At_df.columns.values.tolist()] + Expired_At_df.values.tolist(),value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```